# How to check a checkbox in a jsTree (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, set, jstree

I'm using a jsTree and having a problem to preset the checkboxes via data stored in a cookie.

I'm able to store the clicked checkboxes in a cookie but now I do not know how to check the checkboxes with the data saved within the cookie.

Maybe the problem is the way I create the jsTree because none of the samples I tried up to now work.

To give you some code to understand what I did just have a look at my submit function. This iterates over all of the checked checkboxes and just creates an array of ID's but the ID field is stored in METADATA this way and maybe that's the reason why it do not work the way expected.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({
      "core": { // core options go here
        "multiple": true, // no multiselection
        "themes": {
          "dots": false // no connecting dots between dots
        }
      },

      "json_data": {
        "data": [{
          "data": "Options",
          "metadata": {
            "group": "1"
          },
          "children": [{
            "data": "Option 1",
            "metadata": {
              "id": "1"
            }
          }, {
            "data": "Option 2",
            "metadata": {
              "id": "2"
            }
          }, {
            "data": "Sub Option",
            "children": [{
              "data": "Option 3",
              "metadata": {
                "id": "3"
              }
            }, {
              "data": "Option 4",
              "metadata": {
                "id": "4"
              }
            }, {
              "data": "Option 5",
              "metadata": {
                "id": "5"
              }
            }],
            "metadata": {
              "group": "Master Control"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
      "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox"]
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
      if (jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href")) {
        //alert("Go on..");

      } else {
        //alert("No href defined for this element");
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

I'm able to retrieve the checked nodes and create a list they way below and I guess that there is just a methode just to loop over all of the tree objects, identify them by their ID and just check them but all I tried and found at the web did not help.

```
function submitMe() {
  var checked_ids = [];
  var checked_ids_meta = [];
  var group;

  checked_ids.push("( null ");

  $("#treeViewDiv").jstree("get_checked", null, true).each(function(i, e) {
    if ($(this).data("group") + "" != "undefined") {
      group = $(this).data("group") + "";
    }
    if ($(this).data("id") + "" != "undefined") {
      checked_ids.push($(this).data("id"));
    }
  });

  checked_ids.push(" null )");

  document.getElementById("jsfields").value = checked_ids.join(",");
  alert(document.getElementById("jsfields").value);
  return true;
}
```

Selection is stored within HTML in

```
<input name="jsfields" id="jsfields" size=80 maxlength=256 >
```

What I want to do now  is just to implement the reverse function  to just  check the checkboxes by same ID.

One point I figured out up to now:

So far I see the issue is just to add an ID to the LI tag by using JSON.

I tried something else:

```
<div id="OldFellow">
<ul>

<li id="node_1" ><a>Node 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="leaf_1" ><a>Leaf 1</a></li>
        <li id="leaf_2" ><a>Leaf 2</a></li>
        <li id="leaf_3" ><a>Leaf 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="jsfields" id="jsfields" value="" />


<script>

  $("#OldFellow").jstree(
  {
   "plugins"  : [ "html_data", "types", "themes" , "checkbox" ]
  });

  $.jstree._reference("#OldFellow").check_node('li#leaf_1');

 </script>
```

Code above will pre-select a checkbox within the jsTree.

So the question is:
How to add the ID to HTML LI tag by using JSON as used in this sample?

I fixed it by myself.
It's easy.

```
{
              "data": "Option 3",
              "attr": {"id":"3"},
              "metadata": {"id": "3"}
}
```

It's just required to add the "attr" to the object.
In the real code I used in my program (not shown here) I wrote "attribute" and not "attr".

So now everybody will have a simple example on how to use jsTree with Checkboxes.

Regards
Old Fellow

By the way: To create an issue PLUS a useful solution is not what most of the programmers can do.

Comment: So far I see the issue is just to add an ID to the LI tag by using JASON.

Comment: Could you turn your _minimal_ example into a snippet?